# View, Controller and variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, view

I wrote the code below and it works. But I know this is too much for the view file and most of these code should be written in controllers.
And then, I tried to rewrite it on the controller but got an error message

```
"undefined method `group' for nil:NilClass".
```

Could you give me some advice?

【Before rewriting】

☆show.html.erb(#members)

```
  <div class="message_area">
                <% posts_in_groups = GroupMessage.where(:member_id => params[:id]).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3) %>
                <div class="each_message"> 
                <% posts_in_groups.each do |post_in_group|%>
                    <a href="/groups/<%= post_in_group.group.id %>" ><%= image_tag post_in_group.group.imageurl, :width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + post_in_group.group.name + ")" %></a>
                    <%= 'Page:' + post_in_group.page.to_s + '&' %><%= 'Line:' + post_in_group.line.to_s %>
                    (<%= post_in_group.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                  <div class="group_message">
                    <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= post_in_group.id%>" ><%= truncate(post_in_group.content, { :length => 50} ) %></a></p>
                  </div><!--group_message-->
                  <br>
                    <% end %>
                     <%= will_paginate(posts_in_groups) %> 
                </div><!--each message-- >   

            </div><!--message area-->
```

【After rewriting】

☆show.html.erb(#members)

```
<div class="message_area">
              <div class="each_message">
                    <a href="/groups/<%= @post_in_group.group.id %>" ><%= image_tag @post_in_group.group.imageurl, :width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + @post_in_group.group.name + ")" %></a>
                    <%= 'Page:' + @post_in_group.page.to_s + '&' %><%= 'Line:' + @post_in_group.line.to_s %>
                    (<%= @post_in_group.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                  <div class="group_message">
                    <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= @post_in_group.id%>" ><%= truncate(@post_in_group.content, { :length => 50} ) %></a></p>
                  </div><!--group_message-->
                  <br>
                     <%= will_paginate(@posts_in_groups) %> 
                </div><!--each message-- >   
            </div><!--message area-->
```

☆members_controller

```
@posts_in_groups = GroupMessage.where(:member_id => params[:id]).order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3) 
@posts_in_groups.each do |post_in_group| 
@post_in_group = post_in_group
end
```

☆GroupMessage model

```
class GroupMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :member_id, :group_id, :page, :line

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :group_message_comments, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove this from your controller:

```
@posts_in_groups.each do |post_in_group| 
  @post_in_group = post_in_group
end
```

It doesn't belong there and even if it did, for each item in the collection you would set it to the `@post_in_group` instance variable and that's not what you want given only the last value would ever be set.

And here's how your view code could look like:

```
<div class="message_area">
  <% @posts_in_groups.each do |post| %>  
    <div class="each_message">
      <%= link_to post.group do %>
        <%= image_tag post.group.imageurl, :width => '20', :height => '25' %>
        <%= "(" + post.group.name + ")" %>
      <% end %>

      Page: <%= post.page %> & 
      Line: <%= post.line %>
      (<%= post.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)

      <div class="group_message">
        <p class="message_content">
          <%= link_to truncate(post.content, :length => 50), post %>
        </p>
      </div><!--group_message-->

      <br>      
    </div><!--each message-- >   

    <%= will_paginate(@posts_in_groups) %> 
  <% end %>  
</div><!--message area-->
```

The only thing you really had to remove from your view was the database query, the other pieces are ok to be there.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr.Mauricil Linhares. I think your revise is precise and correct but I got an error message like this. undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass around "Page: <%= post.page>". I have no idea. So, could you tell me why this happens?

Comment: How is the `page` method implemented at `GroupMessage` class?

Comment: GroupMessage model has page column and line column. I added GroupMessage model in the article.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, include <%= debug @posts_in_groups %> before everything in the page and look at the output.

Comment: I checked the content of "post".>> post.page
!! #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fe486344410>:0x007fe48652d8a8>>

Comment: post is only defined inside the each block, you need to include the debug inside the each block.

Comment: I tried but I am using  "better_errors" gem. So, I don't know exactly what kind of information you need..  >> @posts_in_groups
=> nil

Comment: I found the cause of the error. I put @posts_in_groups after  respond_to do |format|